# jmeter slave connection and configuration error

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-5.0, jmeter-4.0

I am running distributed load testing using JMeter. And I configured few new servers but the problem is it throwing the error "non-JRMP server at remote endpoint".

I followed the correct procedure of generating jks, starting the master, starting slave etc. And in both the client and server, I am able to start the jmeter-server.bat files and I see both the machines have started.

Please note - Firewall is already disabled

**Slave:**
Created remote object: UnicastServerRef2 [liveRef: [endpoint:192.168.0.3:3424,SSLRMIServerSocketFactory(host=192.168.0.3, keyStoreLocation=rmi_keystore.jks, type=JKS, trustStoreLocation=rmi_keystore.jks, type=JKS, alias=rmi),SSLRMIClientSocketFactory(keyStoreLocation=rmi_keystore.jks, type=JKS, trustStoreLocation=rmi_keystore.jks, type=JKS, alias=rmi),objID:[-39bc9d70:176812fac65:-7fff, 1785184603072403670]]]

**Master:**
Found ApacheJMeter_core.jar
Created remote object: UnicastServerRef2 [liveRef: [endpoint:192.168.0.1:27849,objID:[-763a229d:176811229c1:-7fff, -5773628807602928343]]]

Can someone suggest if there is anything can be done? All the machines are in same subnet.

**jmeter log of master:**
2020-12-20 09:41:34,608 INFO o.a.j.e.DistributedRunner: Configuring remote engine: 192.168.0.3
2020-12-20 09:41:34,608 INFO o.a.j.r.RmiUtils: Disabling SSL for RMI as server.rmi.ssl.disable is set to 'true'
2020-12-20 09:41:34,624 ERROR o.a.j.e.DistributedRunner: Failed to create engine at 192.168.0.3
java.rmi.ConnectIOException: non-JRMP server at remote endpoint
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.createConnection(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_241]
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.newConnection(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_241]
at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.newCall(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_241]
at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Stub.lookup(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_241]
at org.apache.jmeter.engine.ClientJMeterEngine.getEngine(ClientJMeterEngine.java:72) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.2.1]
at org.apache.jmeter.engine.ClientJMeterEngine.(ClientJMeterEngine.java:85) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.2.1]
at org.apache.jmeter.engine.DistributedRunner.createEngine(DistributedRunner.java:244) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.2.1]
at org.apache.jmeter.engine.DistributedRunner.getClientEngine(DistributedRunner.java:221) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.2.1]
at org.apache.jmeter.engine.DistributedRunner.init(DistributedRunner.java:94) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.2.1]
at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.RemoteStart.doAction(RemoteStart.java:80) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.2.1]
at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.ActionRouter.performAction(ActionRouter.java:88) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.2.1]
at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.ActionRouter.lambda$actionPerformed$0(ActionRouter.java:70) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.2.1]
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_241]
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_241]
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_241]
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_241]
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_241]
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_241]
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_241]
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_241]
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_241]
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_241]
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_241]
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_241]
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_241]
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_241]

Answer (score 0):

You have

- `server.rmi.ssl.disable=true` - on the master
- `server.rmi.ssl.disable=false` - on the slave

It leads to the following situation: master tries to communicate with the slave using plain text and the slave is expecting SSL encrypted messages therefore they cannot "understand" each other hence communication fails.

You either need to [enable SSL on master](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/remote-test.html#setup_ssl), generate the keystore, etc. or to disable it on the slave(s)

More information:

- [Remote hosts and RMI configuration](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#remote)
- [How to Perform Distributed Testing in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-perform-distributed-testing-in-jmeter)
- [Apache JMeter Distributed Testing Step-by-step](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_distributed_testing_step_by_step.html)